# Regex match slug except particular start words

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a route pattern that match slug but not particular words that consist of only the word or have a trailing slash.

I've tried:

```
^(?!(admin|blog)).*$
```

and many various pattern. But still didn't make it.

expected:

```
admin                //not match
blog                 //not match
blog/                //not match
admin-test           //match
test-admin           //match
blog-and-blogwalking //match
any-slug             //obviously match
```

I am not quite good in regex things. Hope somebody can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex.

```
^(?!(?:admin|blog)/?$).*$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN4vH8/4)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:(?!^(?:admin|blog\/?)$).)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kB8pY9/6)

Comment: thanks, great, but I update the question. `test-admin` is not matched by pattern you given.

Comment: or you could try this `^(?:(?!\/(?:admin|blog)(?:\/|$)).)*$` also.

Comment: I'll use @hwnd's answer, he solved the pattern first. But you do great job. many thanks again. I wonder is there any good learning resources to learn regex.

Comment: @egig that's your wish.. I think [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is the best site for learning regex.